# Universal Robot Digital I/O

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a UR3e and would like to access the digital I/O peripherals on the control box.

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368257/universal-robot-digital-i/o/) by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, which driver are you using to control the robot? If you are using the official [ur_robot_driver](https://wiki.ros.org/ur_robot_driver), you should be able to control IO using the `set_io` service. For more information about all the services provided see their [ROS interface documentation](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/master/ur_robot_driver/doc/ROS_INTERFACE.md#set_io-ur_msgssetio).

The service uses the [ur_msgs/SetIO](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/ur_msgs/html/srv/SetIO.html) message type. When trying this out, it might make sense to look at the output from the `io_states` topic (type [ur_msgs/IO](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/ur_msgs/html/msg/IOStates.html)), as the pin numbers should match.

Feel free to ask more if you have specific questions.

---

Originally posted by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) with karma: 176 on 2020-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on 2020-12-22**:
I am using the ur_robot_driver, so this is exactly what I need. Thank you.

**Comment by [Lokney](https://answers.ros.org/users/73010/lokney/) on 2021-04-07**:
Hi, do you know how to use it in C++? Everything what I found about it was in Python. I am using UR10 with ur_robot_driver

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-07**:
@Lokney: it's all standard ROS services, which work from C++ as well.

See [Writing a Simple Service and Client (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2FTutorials.2FWritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node) for the basic client tutorial. Make sure to update the used service definitions.

And looking at `io_states` is a good idea, but I'd recommend consulting the documentation in the [service definition itself](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/ur_msgs/html/srv/SetIO.html).

**Comment by [Lokney](https://answers.ros.org/users/73010/lokney/) on 2021-04-08**:
@gvdhoorn  Thank you for quick answer and useful hints. Below I put part of code in case someone would look for it in future.

```
#include <ur_msgs/SetIO.h>
#include <ur_robot_driver/hardware_interface.h>

...

ros::ServiceClient io_client = node_handle.serviceClient<ur_msgs::SetIO>("/ur_hardware_interface/set_io");

ur_msgs::SetIO io_service;
io_service.request.fun = 1; // Specify what type of IO you want to control, 1 is digital output
io_service.request.pin = 0; // Pin number
io_service.request.state = 1;   // State, as far as I know it can be also voltage

if (io_client.call(gripper_service))
{
  ROS_INFO("Successfull D0 gripper IO states change.");
}
else
{
  ROS_ERROR("Failed to change D0 gripper IO states.");
}
```